# How can you prove 3^n is not O(n^2)?.

Tags: big-o, computer-science

I can obviously tell by inspection that it is not true but I cannot figure out how to prove it with witnesses. Thanks!

Comment: @slawekwin why not cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @shole maybe you are right, I sometimes get confused with how many communities SE has ;)

Comment: btw I do no think it needs to proof, as f(3^n) = O(3^n) and O(3^n) is already another time complexity class compared to O(n^2).  If you really need a proof, just proof f(3^n) = O(3^n) and result is self-explained

Comment: Why not consider the dirty, rotten scoundrel approach - simply graph 3^n - n^2 using Wolfram, like I did here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%5En+-+n%5E2 Clearly, any point that the graph is zero indicates a point at which the two functions are equivalent. Since the value for n at the interesction is less than zero, job's done. Regardless of which method you chose or eschewed, unless you can find a way of having a negative value for n, it's a no-brainer.

Answer (score 0):

Big O is the mathematical domination, so you have just to prove that there is no constant C for which 3^n < C*n^2 after a certain N.

This is not posible since the serie : u(n) = 3^n/n^2 is strictly growing when n tend to infinite.

Demonstration : u(n+1) is equivalent to (at infinite) 3^(n+1)/n^2
                u(n) is equivalent to 3^n/n^2 at infinite

u(n) is so strictly growing, therefore no C can exist